# Why would someone bitwise AND an 8-bit value with a 16-bit mask in C?

Tags: c, emulation

I am trying to replicate Javidx9's NES/MOS6502 CPU code in C# as an academic exercise and I am having trouble understanding the logic behind the implementation of the Zero-Page Addressing Mode. Specifically, I am looking at this [code](https://github.com/OneLoneCoder/olcNES/blob/4dbe2e752d28008f2b28140822605901742366e3/Part%232%20-%20CPU/olc6502.cpp#L392):

```
// Address Mode: Zero Page
// To save program bytes, zero page addressing allows you to absolutely address
// a location in first 0xFF bytes of address range. Clearly this only requires
// one byte instead of the usual two.
uint8_t olc6502::ZP0()
{
    addr_abs = read(pc);    
    pc++;
    addr_abs &= 0x00FF;
    return 0;
}
```

I struggle to understand why `addr_abs &= 0x00FF;` is there, `uint16_t addr_abs` is 16 bits but 
`uint8_t read(uint16_t a);` returns an 8-bit value anyways, so the upper 8 bits (MOS6502 is little-endian) would be 00'd out by default? Am I missing something about how the C compiler/x86 ISA works?

Comment: This could be paranoia, or an artifact of an older behaviour that no longer exists.

Comment: I would guess that there may be other places where `addr_abs` might not be in the range 0-255.  For example, when processing the `zp,x`, `zp,y`, or `(zp,x)` addressing modes, adding `x` or `y` to the operand might yield a value up to 0x01FE, but the load or store should only use the bottom 8 bits of the address anyway.

Comment: @supercat But in this specific case `read` may only ever return the lower `FF` bits and those would be up-casted to `00FF` so the intrinsic value isn't changed, ultimately replacing whichever value `adr_abs` held before. Right?

Comment: @Machinarius: True.  But the programmer might have thought it clearer to mask the value all the time than to only mask it when it could affect the result.

Comment: Guess i'll have to forward this lowly question to the man himself someday: https://twitter.com/javidx9

Comment: @TomKuschel I'm not sure i'm following: incrementing the PC by itself shouldn't affect the value of addr_abs _inside this function_ at all, I think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct `addr_abs &= 0x00ff` isn't needed.

`uint16_t x = n` where `n` is an unsigned 8-bit number (which is the case here). `x` would have it's upper 8 bits cleared. As @tadman stated, there might have been a different method used previously to store the value into `addr_abs` which didn't clear the upper 8 bits.